# HttpURLConnection skipping the FILTER in J2EE application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpurlconnection, form-authentication

I am working on application, which is skipping the FILTERS configured in application while connecting to a http URL through code. One of the filters is UTF8Filter configured with URL pattern `/*`. Below is the code snippet of my URL connection.

```
String protocol = "http";
String port = "50000";
String host = "localhost";
URL url = new URL(protocol + "://" + host + ":" + port + path + "/"
        + fs + "_" + fsv + ".jspx?id=" + wid + "&rt=pdf");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.disconnect();
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
if (jsessionid != null) {
    conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", jsessionid.getName() + "="
            + jsessionid.getValue());
}
logger.info("Before connect....");
conn.connect();
logger.info("After connect...");
logger.info("get response code : " + conn.getResponseCode());//200
```

Below is the log captured from the application.

```
INFO GPBean:201 - Before connect....
INFO GPBean:203 - After connect...
INFO GPBean:207 - get response code : 200
--- It has skipped the filters. Request hasn't gone through the UTF8Filter.
```

Our application is using form based authentication. I see that there is some problem displaying the logon images, because its looking for those images in some other folder, not sure of this.

I have tried removing the authenticaion module and tested the application. It works fine.

Below is the log captured disabling the form based authentication.

```
19 Feb 2015 12:32:19,289  INFO GPBean:201 - Before connect....
19 Feb 2015 12:32:19,292  INFO GPBean:203 - After connect...
19 Feb 2015 12:32:19,363  INFO UTF8Filter:38 - In UTF8Filter class, doFilter() method...
19 Feb 2015 12:32:19,365  INFO UTF8Filter:41 - In UTF8 Filter, Filtering the request
-----some other log messages
19 Feb 2015 12:32:27,017  INFO GPBean:207 - get response code : 200
```

At this point, I am not sure to decide if the problem is with FORM Based authentication or with HTTPUrl connection code or some other configuration. Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
As requested, I am updating with the fragment of my web.xml

```
   <filter>
      <filter-name>RF</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.srk.filters.RF</filter-class>
   </filter>
   <filter>
      <filter-name>UTF8Filter</filter-name>
      <filter-class>com.srk.filters.UTF8Filter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
      </init-param>
   </filter>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>RF</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>RF</filter-name>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>UTF8Filter</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.PersistentFacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.webapp.xmlhttp.BlockingServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.icesoft.faces.component.inputfile.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Persistent Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/xmlhttp/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Blocking Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/block/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/uploadHtml</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What's yout `UTF8Filter` configuration - do you use web.xml or annotations? If I'm not mistaken, you need to add "FORWARD"-Dispatcher to to your Filter Mapping.

Comment: I am using web.xml, no annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your Filter will not intercept the requests made by your code using `HttpURLConnection` as it's not in the scope of a Filter. A Filter can be configured at a container (your tomcat server) level to intercept requests fired using Container API something like RequestDispatcher's `forward()` (or) `include()`. Basically a JAVA EE6 filter can be configured in web.xml with following `<dispatcher>` types

- REQUEST: Only when the request comes directly from the client
- ASYNC:    Only when the asynchronous request comes from the client
- FORWARD:    Only when the request has been forwarded to a component
- INCLUDE: when the request is being processed by a component
  that has been included
- ERROR: Only when the request is being processed with the error
  page mechanism

Comment: But the same HttpUrlConnection is passing through the filter, when I have disabled FORM based authentication right, as mentioned in the question.

Comment: can you add your dispatcher config in filter-mapping in web.xml as well ?

Comment: @srk The default dispatcher setting for a HTTP filter is REQUEST, so only direct requests are filtered. To perform FORM authentication, the servlet container handles the request before it reaches your filter and forwards it to the target form. As Arkantos mentioned, try to specify REQUEST and FORWARD as dispatcher in your web.xml.

Answer (score 1):

The default dispatcher setting for a Servlet Filter is REQUEST, so only direct requests to your resource are being processed by the Servlet Filter.

Form authentication is handled directly by the Servlet Container (and not by the web application itself). The servlet container then forwards the request to your application, to the resource with you login form. Servlet Filters (with their default REQUEST dispatcher binding / mapping) are not processed when the requests are forwarded!

Try to update your Servlet Filter mapping for your UTF8Filter to

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UTF8Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I've tested the solution on Tomcat and the Sevlet Filter gets triggered when FORM authentication is used and dispatcher FORWARD is specified in the Sevlet Filter mapping.